# Passing a PHP Variable by URL Link in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from a MYSQL Query to another page by way of a user clicking on a link.

My query lists out in a table a number of reports. I want the user to be able to click on the report number in the table which would then send the user to another page in which I plan to run another query based on the report number variable sent in the link.

Here is the code that prints out the table rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['report_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='tableleft'>" . $row['inspector'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='tableleft'>" . $row['idate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='tableleft'>" . $row['vendor'] . "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Row one with the string $row['report_number'] is the variable I want to pass to another page by way of a link.

The problem I am having is that this is being executed on a Wordpress page so the page that I have to link to, which is another page in Wordpress, does not have a .php page type.

I can not figure out how to write the link to pass the variable without the .php like in the this example:

```
<a href="edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .php in your link. You can use link like for example: http://site.com/page?id=2&something=10. So, to be clear, just after link to page you want to link to, type "?" and attach variables.

One more thing. You have to be careful with GET and POST variable names in Wordpress, because some of them are restricted and may be truncated from your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, it is now linking to my other page but the link is not passing the variable. My code to pass the variable is: `<td><a href='http://my.site.com/page/page?id='" . $row['report_number'] . "</a>" . $row['report_number'] . "</td>";` The variable is showing up in the table as a link but it is not being passed.

Comment: Edited code, still does not work: code is: `echo "<td><a href='http://my.site.com/page/page?report='" . $row['report_number'] . "</a>" . $row['report_number'] . "</td>";`

Comment: You are using wrong syntax. Try this one: echo "<td><a href='http://my.site.com/page/page?report='" . $row['report_number'] . "</a>" . $row['report_number'] . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Changed syntax to:

```
<td><a href="http://my.site.com/page/page?report=<? echo $row['report_number']; ?>"><? echo $row['report_number']; ?></a></td>
```